# Add a column at specific position using mutate in r

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

I want to add a column at specific position in r, but mutate (xx, .before = "exisiting column) doesn't work right:

```
starwars %>% mutate (new_column =  "Other", .before = 1)

# A tibble: 87 × 16
   name               height  mass hair_color    skin_color  eye_color birth_year sex    gender    homeworld species films     vehicles  starships ICP_type .before
   <chr>               <int> <dbl> <chr>         <chr>       <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>     <chr>   <list>    <list>    <list>    <chr>      <dbl>
 1 Luke Skywalker        172    77 blond         fair        blue            19   male   masculine Tatooine  Human   <chr [5]> <chr [2]> <chr [2]> Other          1
 2 C-3PO                 167    75 NA            gold        yellow         112   none   masculine Tatooine  Droid   <chr [6]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]> Other          1
 3 R2-D2                  96    32 NA            white, blue red             33   none   masculine Naboo     Droid   <chr [7]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]> Other          1
```

It creates a ".before" column rather than adding the new column before the first column.

I tried add_column(), and it works ok. But I still want to know why it goes wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Add sessionInfo, R version, dplyr version. This seems to work fine: `mtcars[1:3, 1:3] %>% mutate(x = "other", .before = 1)` with R version 4.2.2, dplyr_1.0.10.

Comment: It works for me as intended. Which `dplyr` version do you use? Have you maybe loaded another package that masks `mutate`? You could try using `dplyr::mutate` instead

Comment: @r2evans yes, just noticed thanks, edited comment. But still works fine for me.

Comment: @zx8754 Agreed, it seems to be a problem specific to Eleanor's instance.

Comment: Thanks all! It seems I got another package that masks mutate, dplyr::mutate works fine for me now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use mutate and then relocate to specify the position:

```
starwars %>% 
  mutate(new_column =  "Other") %>% 
  relocate(new_column, .before =1)
```